# How can I avoid append errors using concurrent.futures in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, parallel-processing, python-requests, concurrent.futures

I'm trying to create a table with the information of an API. When I analyze game by game it works fine, but when I try to analyze a large number of games using "concurrent.futures" to speed up the process it appends some wrong information to the table. Every time I run the script the errors come up in different rows, it's aleatory.

Also, I have noticed printing the game_ids analyzed, that the script doesn't look them in order. Maybe the error is in this problem.

How can I solve this issue? Thank you!

This is the code I'm using.

```
import requests as r
import pandas as pd
import concurrent.futures

pd.DataFrame(data=None, index=None, columns=None, dtype=None, copy=False)

game_id = [100, 101, 102] #This is an example, I use a large number of games

d = {'game_id'        : [],
     'atbat_num'      : [],
     'play_index'     : [],
     'batter_id'      : [],
     'batter_name'    : [],
     'pitcher_id'     : [],
     'pitcher_name'   : [],
     'runner_id'      : [],
     'runner_name'    : [],
     'event'          : [],
     'start'          : [],
     'end'            : [],
     'movementReason' : []
        }

def get_url(gids):
    url = (f'http://examplelink.com/str(gids)}/')
    req  = r.get(url)
    json = req.json()

    for i in json['allPlays']:

        if 'runners' in i:

            for p in i['runners']:

                d['game_id'].append(gids)
                if 'atBatIndex' in i:
                    d['atbat_num'].append(i['atBatIndex'])
                else: d['atbat_num'].append(None)
                if 'playIndex' in p['details']:
                    d['play_index'].append(p['details']['playIndex'])
                else: d['play_index'].append(None)
                if 'matchup' in i:
                    if 'batter' in i['matchup']:
                        d['batter_id'].append(i['matchup']['batter']['id'])                    
                    else: d['batter_id'].append(None)
                else: d['batter_id'].append(None)
                if 'matchup' in i:
                    if 'batter' in i['matchup']:
                        d['batter_name'].append(i['matchup']['batter']['fullName'])
                    else: d['batter_name'].append(None)
                else: d['batter_name'].append(None)
                if 'matchup' in i:
                    if 'pitcher' in i['matchup']:
                        d['pitcher_id'].append(i['matchup']['pitcher']['id'])
                    else: d['pitcher_id'].append(None)
                else: d['pitcher_id'].append(None)
                if 'matchup' in i:
                    if 'pitcher' in i['matchup']:
                        d['pitcher_name'].append(i['matchup']['pitcher']['fullName'])
                    else: d['pitcher_name'].append(None)
                else: d['pitcher_name'].append(None)
                if 'details' in p:
                    if 'runner' in p['details']:
                        if 'id' in p['details']['runner']:
                            d['runner_id'].append(p['details']['runner']['id'])
                        else: d['runner_id'].append(None)
                    else: d['runner_id'].append(None)
                else: d['runner_id'].append(None)
                if 'details' in p:
                    if 'runner' in p['details']:
                        if 'fullName' in p['details']['runner']:
                            d['runner_name'].append(p['details']['runner']['fullName'])
                        else: d['runner_name'].append(None)
                    else: d['runner_name'].append(None)
                else: d['runner_name'].append(None)
                if 'details' in p:
                    d['event'].append(p['details']['event'])
                else: d['event'].append(None)
                if 'movement' in p:
                    d['start'].append(p['movement']['start'])
                else: d['start'].append(None)
                if 'movement' in p:
                    d['end'].append(p['movement']['end'])
                else: d['end'].append(None)
                if 'details' in p:
                    d['movementReason'].append(p['details']['movementReason'])
                else: d['movementReason'].append(None)

    print(f'Game {gids} analyzed')          

    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        executor.map(get_url, game_id)

table = pd.DataFrame(d)

export_csv = table.to_csv ('runner.csv', index = None, header=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Executor.map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.map) has `func` invoked concurrently so there isn't guarantee that the ordering of the results are according to the iterable.

I am assuming that the data is structured this way so that it can be later presented as tabular data using pandas library.

I suggest that you use a different data structure that doesn't care about the ordering such as a list. [`pandas.DataFrame` data parameter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) can be *dict of lists* or *list of dicts*

```py
d = []
game_id = [100, 101, 102] #This is an example, I use a large number of games

def get_url(gid):
    url = f"http://examplelink.com/{gid}/"
    req = r.get(url)
    json = req.json()

    for i in json["allPlays"]:
        for p in i.get("runners", []):
            matchup = i.get("matchup", {})
            batter = matchup.get("batter", {})
            pitcher = matchup.get("pitcher", {})
            details = p.get("details", {})
            runner = details.get("runner", {})
            event = details.get("event", {})

            d.append(
                dict(
                    game_id=gid,
                    atbat_num=i.get("atBatIndex"),
                    play_index=details.get("playIndex"),
                    batter_id=batter.get("id"),
                    batter_name=batter.get("fullName"),
                    pitcher=pitcher.get("id"),
                    pitcher_name=pitcher.get("fullName"),
                    runner_id=runner.get("id"),
                    runner_name=runner.get("fullName"),
                    event=details.get("event"),
                    start=p.get("movement", {}).get("start"),
                    end=p.get("movement", {}).get("end"),
                    movementReason=details.get("movementReason"),
                )
            )

    print(f"Game {gid} analyzed")

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        executor.map(get_url, game_id)
```

Comment: Thanks! Your code looks very nice and clean. Adding a threading.Lock() to your code could help me too?

Comment: I don't think a lock is necessary for present the data in a tabular format. I can only see it helping to ensure that access to the data structure is claimed at any time by a single thread. I think the benefit of running the job in a `Threadpool` may be lost because threads will have to wait for the lock to be release to write their data. Then again there is significant gain running the network bound step of the job concurrently.

Comment: Thank you! You helped me so much!